# UICollectionView very slow

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm developing a photo gallery and to this purpose, I decided to use the PSTCollectionView (https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView) which basically implements UICollectionView on iOS6 devices, and use a custom View for other iOS. My device is running iOS6.

I use the MKNetworkKit to load images from my server and use cached response to set the images.

The thing is, as soon as I scroll with a minimum of speed, the scroll gets very laggy (my guess due to images setting). As it seems, the cell dequeued are almost most of the time not at the right indexPath, so the image is re-created each time.
Isn't there a way to make the cells dequeue for the good indexpath and reloaded from memory (or cache) instead of reseting the whole image?

Here are some bunches of code:

The Grid (i.e UICollectionView) allocation

```
PSUICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[PSUICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
_gridView = [[PSUICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:[self.view bounds] collectionViewLayout:layout];
_gridView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
_gridView.delegate = self;
_gridView.dataSource = self;
[_gridView registerClass:[ImageGridCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:CollectionViewCellIdentifier];
[_gridView setAlwaysBounceVertical:YES];
```

The cellForRowAtIndexPath :

```
ImageGridCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CollectionViewCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
id photoId = [self.photoIds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell setPhotoId:photoId];
return cell;
```

The setPhotoId method :

```
if (![_photoId isEqualToNumber:photoId])
{
    NSLog(@"set Photo ID %@ for old id %@", photoId, _photoId);
    _photoId = photoId;
    self.image.image = nil;
    __block BOOL imageAlreadySetFromCache = NO;
    self.operation = [[BDRWebService manager] downloadImageWithId:_photoId.stringValue
                                                      isThumbnail:YES
                                                completionHandler:^(UIImage *fetchedImage, NSURL *url, BOOL isInCache) {
                                                    if (isInCache && !imageAlreadySetFromCache)
                                                    {
                                                        self.image.image = fetchedImage;
                                                        NSLog(@"image ready %@ (from cache %d) %@", _photoId, isInCache, NSStringFromCGSize(self.image.image.size));
                                                        imageAlreadySetFromCache = YES;
                                                    }
                                                    else if (!imageAlreadySetFromCache)
                                                    {
                                                        NSLog(@"image ready %@ (from cache %d) %@", _photoId, isInCache, NSStringFromCGSize(self.image.image.size));
                                                        self.image.image = fetchedImage;
                                                    }
                                                } errorHandler:^(MKNetworkOperation *completedOperation, NSError *error) {
                                                }];

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"same cell and image...");
}
```

Here is the log:

```
2012-11-23 11:39:25.431 cellForRow 12
2012-11-23 11:39:25.433 set Photo ID 269 for old id (null)
2012-11-23 11:39:25.436 cellForRow 13
2012-11-23 11:39:25.437 set Photo ID 268 for old id (null)
2012-11-23 11:39:25.440 cellForRow 14
2012-11-23 11:39:25.441 set Photo ID 267 for old id (null)
2012-11-23 11:39:25.463 cellForRow 15
2012-11-23 11:39:25.468 set Photo ID 266 for old id 280
2012-11-23 11:39:25.480 cellForRow 16
2012-11-23 11:39:25.488 set Photo ID 265 for old id 281
2012-11-23 11:39:25.490 cellForRow 17
2012-11-23 11:39:25.504 set Photo ID 264 for old id 279
2012-11-23 11:39:25.511 cellForRow 18
2012-11-23 11:39:25.566 set Photo ID 263 for old id 276
2012-11-23 11:39:25.570 cellForRow 19
2012-11-23 11:39:25.580 set Photo ID 262 for old id 277
2012-11-23 11:39:25.583 cellForRow 20
2012-11-23 11:39:25.591 set Photo ID 261 for old id 278
2012-11-23 11:39:25.654 cellForRow 21
2012-11-23 11:39:25.659 set Photo ID 260 for old id 273
2012-11-23 11:39:25.661 cellForRow 22
2012-11-23 11:39:25.665 set Photo ID 259 for old id 274
2012-11-23 11:39:25.667 cellForRow 23
2012-11-23 11:39:25.671 set Photo ID 258 for old id 275
2012-11-23 11:39:25.690 cellForRow 24
2012-11-23 11:39:25.693 set Photo ID 257 for old id 270
2012-11-23 11:39:25.696 cellForRow 25
2012-11-23 11:39:25.700 set Photo ID 256 for old id 271
2012-11-23 11:39:25.703 cellForRow 26
2012-11-23 11:39:25.707 set Photo ID 255 for old id 272
2012-11-23 11:39:25.733 cellForRow 27
2012-11-23 11:39:25.737 set Photo ID 254 for old id 269
2012-11-23 11:39:25.740 cellForRow 28
2012-11-23 11:39:25.747 set Photo ID 253 for old id 267
2012-11-23 11:39:25.758 cellForRow 29
2012-11-23 11:39:25.776 set Photo ID 252 for old id 268
2012-11-23 11:39:25.872 cellForRow 30
2012-11-23 11:39:25.886 set Photo ID 251 for old id 264
2012-11-23 11:39:25.890 cellForRow 31
2012-11-23 11:39:25.894 set Photo ID 250 for old id 265
2012-11-23 11:39:25.897 cellForRow 32
2012-11-23 11:39:25.906 set Photo ID 249 for old id 266
```

It goes like this forever (maybe it is the appropriate behavior. After all, that is what dequeue is all about right?), but can I make the scroll faster.

I could use all kinds of tips (loading the image with a timer after 0.2 seconds and invalidate it in the prepareForReuse method, cancel the operation (I tried, nothing better so far)), but it wouldn't be very nice.

How can I make the images "stick" to the cells to prevent a new allocation `self.image.image = fetchedImage` everytime?

Answer (score 0):

I think the block will execute in another thread. So **all UI-related operations should be carried out on main thread**

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


      if (isInCache && !imageAlreadySetFromCache)
          {
            self.image.image = fetchedImage;
            NSLog(@"image ready %@ (from cache %d) %@", _photoId, isInCache, NSStringFromCGSize(self.image.image.size));
            imageAlreadySetFromCache = YES;
          }
         else if (!imageAlreadySetFromCache)
         {
           NSLog(@"image ready %@ (from cache %d) %@", _photoId, isInCache, NSStringFromCGSize(self.image.image.size));
           self.image.image = fetchedImage;
         }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**You need to use `PSCollectionViewFlowLayout_` instead of `PSUICollectionViewFlowLayout`, `PSCollectionViewController_` instead of `PSUICollectionViewController`, etc.**

I think this is because you use `PSTCollecitonView` control. If you need legacy support for iOS 5.1 PSTCollectionView as is, but on iOS 6 you need use UICollectionView native. 
In this case, may be PSTCollectionView on iOS 5.* will be slow. But on ios 6.0 all everything should be fine.

From official documentation:

> You want to use UICollectionView, but still need to support older
>   versions of iOS? Then you're gonna love this project. Originally I
>   wrote it for PSPDFKit, my iOS PDF framework that supports text
>   selection and annotations, but this project seemed way too useful for
>   others to keep it for myself :)
>
> If you want to have PSTCollectionView on iOS4.3/5.x and
>   UICollectionView on iOS6, use PSUICollectionView (basically add PS on
>   any UICollectionView* class to get auto-support for older iOS
>   versions) If you always want to use PSTCollectionView, use
>   PSTCollectionView as class names. (replace the UI with PST)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it.